# Android: Low battery & wrong GPS behaviour

Tags: android, gps, batterylevel

I'm developing an app to track the users positions. 
However I've found a weird behaviour of the GPS when the devices have less than 30% of battery (more or less): it stops sending info.
Does anybody know how to avoid this behaviour/find information about it?
Thank you!

UPDATE: I'm trying to find some Google's explanation about this topic. (Which is more or less the same that the flash deactivation when the battery is low). Does anybody know where can I search?

Comment: Does GPS stop providing info through location API or does your application stop sending it to your server?

Comment: The first one, the GPS stops providing info (I guess through location API). The app keeps working properly

Comment: have you checked if you have power saving settings on at android settings. That turns off the GPS

Comment: I've tested  the app with different devices and without power settings activated (to keep the GPS working...)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Android wants to protect the device from battery drainage, if power savings mode is enabled. On ios such an app runs untill the battery is empty.

Comment: The weird thing is that the saving mode wasn't activated... :(

Comment: but you know, if you dont move, there probably is no update of the poisition.